# Neovim builds failing on OS X 10.10.2

Tags: macos, build, makefile, neovim

I should mention that I originally posted this as an [issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2329) on Neovim's tracker, but it hasn't been getting a ton of traction there lately and I'm beginning to suspect that it's more an issue with my setup rather than Neovim itself.

Essentially, I had stopped building neovim nightlies for a few months. Having heard that it's getting integrated terminal support I decided to rebuild using the latest source, only to get a persistent, odd error. No matter what my build settings are, it always boils down to `make` hitting an error when it has to compile a file called `loop.so`. I hadn't noticed this issue with any other software I try to build, but I suspect it could be an issue with my environment.

Does anyone here know what this file's role is, and why the compilation could be failing at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a bad `typedef` in a `libuv` header, `object.h`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the full Xcode app and not just the command line. This fixed the issue for me.